# How to make this code generic

Tags: python, dns, html-parsing

I have a use case telling that when a tag is `link` and it's attributes are `rel=dns-prefetch` and `prefetch` then just say that pre resolving dns is enabled.

I have made a flag as `pre_resolve_dns_enabled` and set it to true as follows.

```
class Extractor(HTMLParser):

    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.pre_resolve_dns_enabled = False

    def feed(self, data):
        HTMLParser.feed(self,data)

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'link' and ('rel', 'dns-prefetch') in attrs:
            self.pre_resolve_dns_enabled = True
        if tag == 'link' and ('rel', 'prefetch') in attrs:
            self.prefetch_enabled = True
```

And I have written two methods to return the status.

```
def is_pre_resolve_dns_enabled(self):
    return self.pre_resolve_dns_enabled

def is_prefetch_enabled(self):
    return self.prefetch_enabled
```

Is there a way I can effectively make the `handle_starttag` method generic so that I do not have to hardcode the tag and query the attars like that and get rid of `is_pre_resolve_dns_enabled` and `is_prefetch_enabled`.

Comment: Did you thought about using third-party libraries?

Comment: I was thinking of using Beautiful soup here

Comment: Which tag are you checking? The root-tag?

Comment: Just to be clear. If theres one or more link tags with a rel attribute with the value dns-prefetch pre_resolve_dns_enabled should be set to true? Same for prefetch_enabled?

Comment: Yes one tag and the flag is set to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this with Bs4 You could use this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)  # Or some xml-like structure
# This will select all link tags which have a rel attribute with value dns-prefetch.
if len(soup.select('link[rel=dns-prefetch]')) > 0:
    self.pre_resolve_dns_enabled = True
if len(soup.select('link[rel=prefetch]')) > 0:
    self.prefetch_enabled = True
```

Comment: You mean the string link[rel=dns-prefetch]? It snot quite clear what you want